# Windows 10 - Critical Error 41, three "hard hangs", only one event with event log

Tags: windows-10, freeze

Over the last two days my computer has been experiencing seemingly random "hard hangs". As far as I know, all the hardware is sound, and I've not installed any new drivers recently. The only program I've installed is SublimeText. Three of the stop errors were unable to gather information, and only one did. I really have no idea what to do, could really use help. Thank you.

[Link to Error Files in my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3L72Q4D-LjjaUhkVG9ycFhuaVU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/en-us I reboot is because of this BSOD: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/Windows/Hardware/ff559239(v=vs.85).aspx Share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: have you uploaded the dmp file?

Comment: There is no dmp file. The thing hard hangs and isn' about to create one. I did check, dmp files are enabled.